# How to redefine lambda anonymous class in java

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, javaagents

JDK8 convert lambda expressions to anonymous class in

```
InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.spinInnerClass() {
    return UNSAFE.defineAnonymousClass(targetClass, classBytes, null);
}
```

I'm writing a javaagent, use asm to modify `classBytes`(add a method) and pass it to `defineAnonymousClass`, but the method end up with a ClassNotFoundException of this anonymous class. is there any way I can modify the content of annonymous classBytes?

Answer (score 0):

Transforming anonymously loaded classes is tricky. Are you retranforming already loaded classes that represent such classes? If so, watch out that `Class::getName` does not return the actual binary name of the class but adds a random hash such as `my.DefinedType/12345` where you would need to strip the latest numbers.

Also, you cannot reference such classes directly from another class but you need to reference them directly from either the reflection API or ideally a method handle. You cannot look up such classes from a class loader which is why they are called anonymous.

Finally, when installing a class file transformer, the loading of such anonymous classes is not registered with the transformer. The easiest way of dealing with such classes is to patch the lambda meta factory that is responsible for creating lambda types. You can do so easily by using for example [Byte Buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy) which allows you to create an agent:

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
  .with(LambdaTransformationStrategy.ENABLED)
  .type(someMatcher)
  .transform(someTransformer)
  .installOn(instrumentation);
```

Calling this, under the covers, Byte Buddy rewrites the JVM's default lambda meta factory class and replaces it with its own code generation where such instrumentation is possible.

Comment: other classes can refer to an anonymous class directly, if they are also anonymous classes and have a patched constant pool (that’s the 3rd parameter of `defineAnonymousClass`). In that case, it also doesn’t matter, which name they are using.

Comment: That is true. But this does not apply for classes describing lambda expressions.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm not trying to retranforming already loaded class, but just modify the bytes of an anonymous class before it is created. still don't know why it's not working. what about define the anonymous class by `targetClass.getClassLoader.defineClass(modifyedAnonymousClassBytes)` ? is there any side affects?

Comment: @nzomkxia: When you try to change the the byte codes of a class at loading time, you have to do it inside an implementation of `ClassFileTransformer`. In that case, you should call neither `defineClass` nor `defineAnonymousClass`, you should simply *return* the modified byte code. Passing the byte code to the `defineClass` method of targetClass’ `ClassLoader` does rarely work. First, anonymous classes may access `private` methods of the target class, which is not allowed for ordinary classes, second, `targetClass` may be a bootstrap class, having a `null` class loader.